# PHP cURL sending empty parameters

Tags: php, curl

cURL is new to me. I'm trying to integrate an api via PHP cURL. The api that I'm trying to access requires that parameters be sent as key-value pairs, not json. Their example cURL request in their docs is:

```
curl -i -X POST -d  'api_key=my_api_key' -d 
'email=john@doe.com' -d "first_name=Joe" -d "last_name=Doe" -d 
"cust_id=cus_401" 
https://serviceurl.com/api/create
```

My code is apparently sending empty parameters to their api.

```
    $service_url = 'https://serviceurl.com/api/create';

    $curl = curl_init($service_url);

    $email = $this->session->userdata('email');

    $postArray = array(
        'api_key' => 'my_api_key',
        'email' => $email,
    );

    $curl_post_data = $postArray;
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post_data);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);


    $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
    if ($curl_response === false) {
        $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        die('error occured during curl exec. Additioanl info: ' . var_export($info));
    }
    curl_close($curl);
    echo $curl_response;
    echo $info;
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: their example has more fields than your code - you have only used two - could that be the reason? Also - there is a subtle difference in the POST method - either `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` depending upon whether you use a simple array as the POST data or `http_build_query` to create the data string

Comment: The additional fields are not required. Just the api key and the email parameters. Could you expound on the difference in the POST method a little further. I don't quite understand. Thanks

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php ~ look for `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` to read the description. Basically - `If value is an array, the Content-Type header will be set to multipart/form-data` so it depends upon whether the api is expecting urlencoded or multipart data

Answer (score 2):

your curl php code is sending the data in `multipart/form-data` format, but as evident by their cli invocation example, their api wants the data in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format.

[as explained by the curl_setopt docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php), when you give CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS an array, it will automatically be encoded to `multipart/form-data`, if you give it a string, `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` will automatically be assumed, and is what their curl cli invocation is using.

lucky for you, PHP has a dedicated function for encoding arrays to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format, called `http_build_query`, thus
`curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($curl_post_data));` will fix your issue of `apparently sending empty parameters`.

also, if there is a problem setting any of your options, curl_setopt will return bool(false), which your code is completely ignoring, and would go unnoticed, you should fix that, consider using an error-catching setopt wrapper, like

```
function ecurl_setopt ( /*resource*/$ch , int $option , /*mixed*/ $value ):bool{
    $ret=curl_setopt($ch,$option,$value);
    if($ret!==true){
        //option should be obvious by stack trace
        throw new RuntimeException ( 'curl_setopt() failed. curl_errno: ' . $ch .'. curl_error: '.curl_error($ch) );
    }
    return true;
}
```