# PHP - curl post view request body (parameters)

Tags: php, apache, curl, php-curl

I get an error response for missing parameter when posting cURL POST method, 
I'm adding an array of parameters to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS the following way:

```
$service = "AutoInsuranceFormPostService";
$method = "autoInsurancePublisherFormPost";
$userAgent = "Mozilla%2F5.0+%28Linux%3B+Android+4.4.4%3B+Z752C+Build%2FKTU84P%29+AppleWebKit%2F537.36+%28KHTML%2C+like+Gecko%29+Chrome%2F36.0.1985.135+Mobile+Safari%2F537.36";
$payload = $encodedPayLoad;

$parameters = array (
    'service' => $service,
    'method' => $method,
    'UserAgent' => $userAgent,
    'payload' => $payload
);
```

With:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$parameters);
```

Since the response is saying missing parameter "service", I figured I need to debug the request body. 
I managed to get the headers with:

```
curl_getinfo($ch)
```

I also attempted to use:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
```

But unfortunately in both cases I only got the headers and not the body (the parameters values).

Full curl execution function:

```
function openurl($url, $postvars) {

$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
$verbose = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $verbose);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postvars);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, '3');

$result = curl_exec($ch);

rewind($verbose);
$verboseLog = stream_get_contents($verbose);
echo "Verbose information:\n<pre>", htmlspecialchars($verboseLog), "</pre>\n";
return $result;
}
```

Verbos information:

```
Content-Length: 6659
Expect: 100-continue
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; boundary=------------------------45b2d9f6776306b0

< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Thu, 12 Jul 2018 16:32:52 GMT
< Server: Apache
< Cache-Control: public
< ORIGIN: S_CACHE
< Vary: User-Agent,Accept-Encoding
< Set-Cookie: _qs_origin=s-cache; path=/;
< Set-Cookie: _qs_deviceType=; path=/;
< Content-Length: 141
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1
<
```

This output is useless for me since I cannot see how the parameters were sent and those cannot fix their format.

The response I get is:

```
{"Status":"Fail","StatusCode":"400","ResponseMessage":"\"service\" parameter empty! || \"method\" parameter empty! ","SkipMatchingFlag":"No"}
```

I have been searching for a solution all day long, I've seen a ton of answers on "How to see the RESPONSE body", and "How to see the request HEADERS".

 But none for "How to see the request body", so any help would be much appreciated,

Best regards.

Comment: the answer to this question may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49023736/php-curl-sending-empty-parameters

Comment: Thanks, I have browsed the answers over there, unfortunately I have already set: 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
(edited question with full cURL execution)